# Error installing HHVM at the very end CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos6, hhvm

Carefully followed the inscructions at: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-CentOS-6.6

Get to the very end and it fails. Rather frustrating. Any idea what the problem might be?

```
-- Found LIBGLOG: /usr/local/lib/libglog.so
-- Could NOT find LIBINOTIFY (missing:  LIBINOTIFY_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find LIBICONV (missing:  LIBICONV_LIBRARY)
-- Performing Test LIBICONV_CONST
-- Performing Test LIBICONV_CONST - Failed
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.23")
-- Found LIBMEMCACHED: /usr/local/lib/libmemcached.so
-- Found PCRE: /usr/lib64/libpcre.so
-- Performing Test SYSTEM_PCRE_HAS_JIT
-- Performing Test SYSTEM_PCRE_HAS_JIT - Failed
-- System PCRE does not have JIT enabled - will use hhvm-third-party/pcre
-- Found libevent: /usr/lib64/libevent.so
-- Looking for evhttp_bind_socket_with_fd
-- Looking for evhttp_bind_socket_with_fd - not found
-- Could NOT find LibUODBC (missing:  LIBODBC_LIBRARIES LIBODBC_INCLUDE_DIRS)
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so (found version "7.19.7")
-- Looking for curl_multi_select
-- Looking for curl_multi_select - not found
-- Looking for curl_multi_wait
-- Looking for curl_multi_wait - not found
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so (found version "2.7.6")
-- Found LibXslt: /usr/lib64/libxslt.so (found version "1.1.26")
-- Found EXPAT: /usr/lib64/libexpat.so (found version "2.0.1")
-- Using third-party bundled libsqlite3
-- Could NOT find DOUBLE_CONVERSION (missing:  DOUBLE_CONVERSION_LIBRARY DOUBLE_CONVERSION_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Using third-party bundled double-conversion
-- Could NOT find LZ4 (missing:  LZ4_LIBRARY LZ4_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Using third-party bundled LZ4
-- Could NOT find FastLZ (missing:  FASTLZ_LIBRARY FASTLZ_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Using third-party bundled fastlz
-- Could NOT find LIBZIP (missing:  LIBZIP_LIBRARY LIBZIP_INCLUDE_DIR_ZIP LIBZIP_INCLUDE_DIR_ZIPCONF)
-- Using third-party bundled libzip
-- Found ICU header files in /usr/include
-- Found ICU libraries: /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so
-- Performing Test JEMALLOC_VERSION_MINIMUM
-- Performing Test JEMALLOC_VERSION_MINIMUM - Success
-- Found jemalloc: /usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so
-- Found Intel TBB
CMake Error at CMake/FindMcrypt.cmake:31 (message):
  Could NOT find mcrypt library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:306 (find_package)
  CMake/HPHPSetup.cmake:125 (include)
  third-party/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/local/hhvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/usr/local/hhvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
gahoachma@remote [/usr/local/hhvm]# sudo sed -i -e 's/$/..\/..\/..\/lib\/libmemcached.so/g' hphp/hhvm/CMakeFiles/hhvm.dir/link.txt
sed: can't read hphp/hhvm/CMakeFiles/hhvm.dir/link.txt: No such file or directory
gahoachma@remote [/usr/local/hhvm]# sudo sed -i -e 's/$/..\/..\/..\/lib\/libmemcached.so/g' hphp/hhvm/CMakeFiles/hhvm.dir/link.txt
sed: can't read hphp/hhvm/CMakeFiles/hhvm.dir/link.txt: No such file or directory
gahoachma@remote [/usr/local/hhvm]# sudo make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
gahoachma@remote [/usr/local/hhvm]# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
gahoachma@remote [/usr/local/hhvm]# hhvm --version
-bash: hhvm: command not found
gahoachma@remote [/usr/local/hhvm]#
```

Comment: Seems that you need to install mcrypt library, as it is implied by the message: Could NOT find mcrypt library.

Comment: Checked that & : Package mcrypt-2.6.8-10.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: What about the dev version of this package? Sometimes you have the regular package, with just the libraries needed, as third party libraries, by other applications, and sometimes you need to the -dev version, just to compile other projects. Also, if you really have the package that is needed, you can open the file FindMcrypt.cmake, located in the CMake folder, and edit the line where it tries to find the library, adding the correct path.